# How can I convert a Number.Double Access column value to a Decimal?

Tags: c#, ms-access, double, decimal, currency

Since decimal is preferable to double for monetary values (see David's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when])), I am trying to change my code to use decimal instead of double. IOW, I changed this:

```
public class InventoryItem
{
. . .
    public double UnitCost { get; set; }
    public double UnitList { get; set; }
    public double OpenQty { get; set; }
. . .
```

...to this:

```
public class InventoryItem
{
. . .
    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitList { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenQty { get; set; }
. . .
```

But that gave me grief in other code, namely "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'decimal'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*" in this code:

```
// I changed "double openQty" to "decimal openQty"
decimal openQty = (oleDbD8aReader["open_qty"] is DBNull
                                ? 0.00
                                : Convert.ToDouble(oleDbD8aReader["open_qty"]));
```

So, I tried changing the "Convert.ToDouble()" to "*Convert.ToDecimal()" but that errors out with, "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'double' and 'decimal'*"

The data being retrieved is from MS Access, where the columns under discussion are of type Number and, more specifically, Double (Number.Double, as it were).

How can I coerce/convert Access Double to the "more better" Decimal type?

Comment: Do you have some difficulty in editing the table to Currency data type in MS Access?

Comment: That's a possibility, but these tables exist on each user's machine, and besides, the code that deals with that is actually in a different (not mine) project altogether. So, converting the data from double to decimal would be far easier.

Comment: Your variable openQty is a decimal but you're calling Convert.ToDouble().  You need to call Convert.ToDecimal(), or put a (decimal) at the front of the expression.  (decimal)(oleDbD8aReader["open_qty"] is DBNull
                                ? 0.00M
                                : Convert.ToDecimal(oleDbD8aReader["open_qty"]));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not with the ".ToDecimal()" but with the "0.00"

This:

```
decimal openQty = (oleDbD8aReader["open_qty"] is DBNull
    ? 0.00
    : Convert.ToDecimal(oleDbD8aReader["open_qty"]));
```

...had to become this:

```
decimal openQty = (oleDbD8aReader["open_qty"] is DBNull
    ? 0.00M
    : Convert.ToDecimal(oleDbD8aReader["open_qty"]));
```

(simply appending the "M" to the "0.00" shut up the compiler critics.